# How to change indent of bullets in Google Slides Master

Tags: google-slides

I have created a bullet list in a Google Slide, and it adopts the indentation as specified in the Master Slide. I can select the Level One bullets, and manually change their indentation so the layout is more compact. Is there a way to apply the new indentations to the Master Slide so they are automatically applied to any new slides that are created. I tried to make the same changes in the Master Slide, but all the "indentation" controls are grayed-out on the Format sidebar.

Comment: Yeap, this is driving me crazy too. It seems like a pretty simple option to add, yet issues raised on google support went unanswered and are closed. See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/14083157 and  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3750758.